# How do I search [] in json by sql

Tags: mysql, json

How do I search [] where in json like

```
{"buyer_uni_no":{"info":[],"Pos":[[0,0,0,0]]}}
```

And there are my sql query I try but didn't work.

```
select * from test where JSON_VALUE(myjson,'$.buyer_uni_no.info') = '[]'
select * from test where JSON_VALUE(myjson,'$.buyer_uni_no.info[0]') = ''
```

Comment: probably you need to use `JSON_LENGTH`, ie `select * from test where JSON_LENGTH(myjson,'$.buyer_uni_no.info') = 0`

Comment: @IłyaBursov you should add that as an answer. Looks like that'll give OP the needed records.

Comment: @IłyaBursov It's work!Thank you~

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `JSON_LENGTH` function on the array:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE JSON_LENGTH(json->"$.buyer_uni_no.info") = 0;
```

### Demo

Another way, checking for a literal empty array `[]`:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE CAST(myjson->"$.buyer_uni_no.info" AS CHAR(50)) = '[]';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
JSON_LENGTH is work!
But (json->"$.buyer_uni_no.info") need to change to (json,'$.buyer_uni_no.info').

Comment: What I gave above should at least run on MySQL 8+.  Maybe you are using an earlier version of MySQL where the JSON API be slightly different.